# Calculating ranking for a feed on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I rank API's by upvotes on [this site](https://api.blockspring.com/blocks).

I'm calculating the score on every page load. This is expensive and slow and the page load is taking ~5 seconds.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Every time a new post is created, do I need to rerank everything using a background job? How about every time a vote is submitted and every time a post grows older by an hour?

This seems like a common problem to have on any site that is ranking dependent on time + votes.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to say for sure. Did your roll this yourself, or are you using a gem?

Answer (score 0):

If you can give some info on your models and ranking system I can refine this answer, but here's my suggestion based on the info you've provided thus far:

Create a column on your AR model called `count`.

When a new Api object is created, set the `count` column to `0`. When it gets upvoted, do this:

```
def upvote
  @api = Api.find_by_id(params[:id])
  new_count = @api.count + 1
  @api.update_attributes(:count => new_count)
end
```

You can do the opposite for downvotes.

Then in your view, just do this in the loop:

```
<% @apis.each do |api| %>
  <%= api.count %>
<% end %>
```

That will stop counting on page loads, and will simply pull a value from the database. Hope this helps, and cool idea for a site. If you want to use a gem that I've liked pretty well so far, [Thumbs Up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) is a good option.